# Truncate Vs Delete and Table Locks SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, truncate

Right now I am having an issue with a stored procedure that is locking up when running.

It's a conversion from Sybase.

The stored procedure originally would do

```
TRUNCATE TABLE appInfo
```

Then repopulate the data within the same stored procedure, but in SQL Server this seems to be causing locks to the users.

Its not a high traffic database.

The change I tried was the to do

```
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE TABLE appInfo
COMMIT TRAN
```

Then repopulate the data, but the users are getting a `NO_DATA_FOUND` error on this one.

So if I `TRUNCATE` they get data, but it causes a lock

If I do a delete there is no data found.

Anyone have any insight into this condition and a solution? I was thinking of taking the truncate out to a separate stored procedure and called from within the parent procedure, but that might just be pushing the issue down the road and not actually solving it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Truncate because you want to reset the identity? Also is "DELETE [TABLE]" meant to be "DELETE * FROM [TABLE]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you truncate a table the entire table is locked (from MSDN https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570%28v=sql.105%29.aspx - ***TRUNCATE TABLE always locks the table and page but not each row.***) When you issue a delete table it locks a row, deletes it, and then locks the next row and deletes it. Your users are continuing to hit the table as it is happening. I would go with truncate because its almost always faster.